# How to use form as a service if form service is extending another service in Symfony3?

Tags: php, symfony

How can I use form as a service if my form service is extending another service?

For example if I have parent form service like this:

```
project.modelbundle.parent_form_type:
    class: Path/To/Parent/Form/Class/name
    calls:
        - [callMethod1, ["arg1"]]
        - [callMethod2]
```

And form that extends service above that I want to use in controller:

```
project.modelbundle.my_specific_form_service:
    parent: project.modelbundle.parent_form_type        
    arguments: ['@service_container', '@request_stack', 'some_string_arg']
```

How can I use defined service project.modelbundle.my_specific_form_service as form in controller?

Comment: Not sure you can under S3 since the class name needs to be unique so two services using the same class will not work.  I think you will need to extend the actual class.

Comment: What boders me even more is that now you can not pass form instance to another service. For example you can not do '@project.modelbundle.parent_form_type' even if form service is not extending another service.